# How can I make list counters clickable with only CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a list with numbering generated by CSS

```css
ol>li {
  counter-increment: list;
}

ol>li::marker {
  content: '('counter(list, decimal) ')'
}
```

```html
<ol type="1">
  <li id="MyID">A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ol>
```

Is there a javascript-less way to make the counters (i.e. "(1)") clickable? My goal is to click on the counter and go to a link to that specific list item, something like [www.mysite.domain/page#MyID](http://www.mysite.domain/page#MyID). I am asking for a pure HTML+CSS because I am actually generating the html to be then pasted into a wiki.

Comment: If the list goes to a  link, then you should use the <a> (anchor) tag. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Why not make the *entire* *"(N)Some text"* clickable?

Comment: @jordan I want to link TO the listed items, they are not links.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Possible, but that interferes with copying text somewhat.

Comment: @sup true that. Not everybody know that you can copy link text by holding the Alt key.  I'm afraid you will need to edit HTML. Or eventually use JavaScript or a combination of the three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use custom CSS Counter for this**

```css
.myList {
  counter-reset: myList;
}

.myList li a:before {
  counter-increment: myList;
  content: "(" counter(myList) ") ";
}
.myList li{
  list-style:none;
}
.myList li a{
  color: #000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="myList">
  <li><a href="http://www.mysite.domain/page#MyID">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.mysite.domain/page#MyID">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.mysite.domain/page#MyID">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.mysite.domain/page#MyID">D</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I edited the answer, I was actually asking for only the counters to be clickable, not also the text, but that is easily done by having the A tag empty of any visible text. This works like a charm!